# removeFirst and addLast methods of LinkedList Class are Unknown

Tags: c#

I have a problem with my  code in C# . if i  click in compiler button , I get the following errors

> '`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<int?>`'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'removeFirst' and no extension method
>   'removeFirst' accepting a first
>   argument of type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<int?>`'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?).

and

> '`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<Hanoi_tower.Sol>`'
>   does not contain a definition for
>   'addLast' and no extension method
>   'addLast' accepting a first argument
>   of type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList<Hanoi_tower.Sol>`'
>   could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

This is my program

```
using System.;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Hanoi_tower
{
   public class Sol
    {

public LinkedList<int?> tower1 = new LinkedList<int?>();
   public LinkedList<int?> tower2 =new LinkedList<int?>();
   public LinkedList<int?> tower3 =new LinkedList<int?>();
   public int depth;

   public LinkedList<Sol> neighbors;

    public Sol(LinkedList<int?> tower1, LinkedList<int?> tower2, LinkedList<int?> tower3)
    {
        this.tower1 = tower1;
        this.tower2 = tower2;
        this.tower3 = tower3;

        neighbors = new LinkedList<Sol>();
    }

    public virtual void getneighbors()
    {

        Sol temp = this.copy();
        Sol neighbor1 = this.copy();
        Sol neighbor2 = this.copy();
        Sol neighbor3 = this.copy();
        Sol neighbor4 = this.copy();
        Sol neighbor5 = this.copy();
        Sol neighbor6 = this.copy();


        if (temp.tower1.Count != 0)
        {

            if (neighbor1.tower2.Count != 0)
            {
                if (neighbor1.tower1.First.Value < neighbor1.tower2.First.Value)
                {
                    neighbor1.tower2.AddFirst(neighbor1.tower1.RemoveFirst);
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor1);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                neighbor1.tower2.AddFirst(neighbor1.tower1.RemoveFirst());
                neighbors.AddLast(neighbor1);
            }



            if (neighbor2.tower3.Count != 0)
            {
                if (neighbor2.tower1.First.Value < neighbor2.tower3.First.Value)
                {
                    neighbor2.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor2.tower1.RemoveFirst());
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor2);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                neighbor2.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor2.tower1.RemoveFirst());
                neighbors.AddLast(neighbor2);
            }

        }




        //-------------

        if (temp.tower2.Count != 0)
        {


            if (neighbor3.tower1.Count != 0)
            {
                if (neighbor3.tower2.First.Value < neighbor3.tower1.First.Value)
                {
                    neighbor3.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor3.tower2.RemoveFirst());
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor3);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                neighbor3.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor3.tower2.RemoveFirst());
                neighbors.AddLast(neighbor3);
            }



            if (neighbor4.tower3.Count != 0)
            {
                if (neighbor4.tower2.First.Value < neighbor4.tower3.First.Value)
                {
                    neighbor4.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor4.tower2.RemoveFirst());
                    neighbors.AddLast(neighbor4);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                neighbor4.tower3.AddFirst(neighbor4.tower2.RemoveFirst());
                neighbors.AddLast(neighbor4);
            }


        }


        //------------------------

        if (temp.tower3.Count() != 0)
        {


            if (neighbor5.tower1.Count() != 0)
             {
                if(neighbor5.tower3.ElementAtOrDefault() < neighbor5.tower1.ElementAtOrDefault())
                {
                    neighbor5.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor5.tower3.RemoveFirst());
                neighbors.AddLast(neighbor5);
                }
             }
                 else
                 {
             neighbor5.tower1.AddFirst(neighbor5.tower3.RemoveFirst());
             neighbors.AddLast(neighbor5);
                 }



            if (neighbor6.tower2.Count() != 0)
             {
                if(neighbor6.tower3.element() < neighbor6.tower2.element())
                {
                    neighbor6.tower2.addFirst(neighbor6.tower3.removeFirst());
                 neighbors.addLast(neighbor6);
            }
             }
                else
                {
             neighbor6.tower2.addFirst(neighbor6.tower3.removeFirst());
             neighbors.addLast(neighbor6);
                }

            }
    }

        public override string ToString()
{

    string str;

    str="tower1"+ tower1.ToString() + "   tower2" + tower2.ToString() + "   tower3" + tower3.ToString();


    return str;

}


        public Sol copy()

{

    Sol So;
     LinkedList<int> l1= new LinkedList<int>();
     LinkedList<int> l2=new LinkedList<int>();
     LinkedList<int> l3 = new LinkedList<int>();


     for(int i=0;i<=this.tower1.Count() -1;i++)
     {

         l1.AddLast(tower1.get(i));

     }



      for(int i=0;i<=this.tower2.size()-1;i++)
     {

         l2.addLast(tower2.get(i));

     }

      for(int i=0;i<=this.tower3.size()-1;i++)
     {

         l3.addLast(tower3.get(i));

     }


      So = new Sol(l1, l2, l3);
     return So;

}



        public bool Equals(Sol sol)

{

    if (this.tower1.Equals(sol.tower1) & this.tower2.Equals(sol.tower2) & this.tower3.Equals(sol.tower3))
        return true;

    return false;

}


        public virtual bool containedin(Stack<Sol> vec)
     {

         bool found =false;

         for(int i=0;i<= vec.Count-1;i++)
         {
            if(vec.get(i).tower1.Equals(this.tower1) && vec.get(i).tower2.Equals(this.tower2) && vec.get(i).tower3.Equals(this.tower3))
            {
                found=true;
              break;
         }

         }

         return found;
     }

}


    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't Intellisense automatically help with the casing? Is it possible something's messed up with their environment?

Comment: @Bill the Lizard ~ Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

C# is case-sensitive.  The correct method names are [`RemoveFirst`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132181%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and [`AddLast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132177%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), with a capital R and A.

All .NET methods and properties are done in Pascal casing, where the first letter of each word is capitalized.

Comment: Incidentally, Java uses camel-case, and its `LinkedList` has a `removeFirst`.

Comment: FWIW, it's typically called PascalCase in C# due to Anders :)

    - http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?PascalCase
    - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2004/02/03/67024.aspx

Comment: Additionally, RemoveFirst returns a void, and where he's using it he's adding a T to the list, so he's trying to add a void to the list... I don't think that'll work like he wants. Unless those add the appropriate t[1|2|3] kind of like how `x[i].value = i--` vs `x[i].value = --i` are different behaviors...

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to capitalize correctly:  RemoveFirst and AddLast

Here's a link to all the methods of LinkedList:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h64606bk(v=VS.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

C# is case sensitive, so the method names `removeFirst` and `RemoveFirst` are not the same.  The code snippet you posted has the correct capitolization, but the errors you provided do not.  Which is correct?

This is a listing of the .NET `List` class' methods. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h64606bk(v=VS.100).aspx

Edit:

If you are looking for something similar to the canonnical `pop` functionality of a stack, where the object being removed is returned by the function, then you may be disappointed.  You will need to first use something like `t1.AddFirst(t2[0])` before you call `RemoveFirst()` on t2.

Another Edit:

Okay, this is really another question, but here's the way you might go about moving an object from one list to another, in pseudocode since I'm pretty sure this is a homework question and I don't want to hand you the answer on a silver platter.

```
Function MoveObject(list1, index1, list2, index2)  
    add object at index1 in list1 to list2 at index2
    remove object at index2 from list2
```

You would call a function similar to that each time you want to move an object from one list to another.  If you don't need to specify indices, then you could just pass the function two lists and have it assume index 0 where I've specified variables.

Comment: I could not solve the problem ... 
I modify the question and raise the full program

Comment: Agreed at the stacklike behavior needs to be revised on the program. Encapsulation as a method may be better than dual line code snippets everywhere.

Comment: :(  :(  :(  :( :(    help me,plz

Comment: I've modified the answer with some pseudocode for how you might want to do that.  Throw that function coded in your language at the end and call it, and it ought to work alright.

Comment: Idid not understand your speech .. You have to implement all means, but the program does not work with me and show me the same errors

Comment: UP ^ ^  ^   ^   ^   ^   ^    ^    ^    ^